# Jupyter Notebook : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I am using Jupyter notebook with app insights in azure to analyse the data. I am getting the data as follows,

> {'xaxis': ['2018-04-15T03:00:00Z', '2018-04-15T07:00:00Z'], 'yaxis':
>   [62, 26]}

I am using seaborn to plot the data on a bar chart,

```
import seaborn as sns #modern visualization
```

and plotting using the following,

```
sns.barplot(y = axes['yaxis'], x = axes['xaxis'], orient='h');
```

it throws an error saying

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Can you try `sns.barplot(y = axes['yaxis'], x = axes['xaxis'], orient='v');` changing `orient='v'`? May be explanation in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39937451/5916727 will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following answer in [github issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/994)

- If your x variable is categorical then it can not draw a horizontal barplot.
- If your y variable is categorical then it can not draw a vertical barplot.

One way could be to change orient to `v`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

axes = {'xaxis': ['2018-04-15T03:00:00Z', '2018-04-15T07:00:00Z'], 'yaxis': [62, 26]}
sns.barplot(y = axes['yaxis'], x = axes['xaxis'], orient='v');
```

Result:

[image]

Or to draw horizontal you can try changing the x and y:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

axes = {'xaxis': ['2018-04-15T03:00:00Z', '2018-04-15T07:00:00Z'], 'yaxis': [62, 26]}
sns.barplot(x = axes['yaxis'], y = axes['xaxis'], orient='h');
```

Result:

[image]